# Make a button's active state show my search box

Tags: html, css, modx

I've got a button with a search label. The idea is that when you click the button (and put it in the active state) my search field which is put on display:none becomes visible. My current setup doesn't seem to work however. I've created a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mKbd8/) containing my problem. Since this already is in ModX i cant paste the exact code but if clicking the button shows the text it yields the same result.

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="search_function">[[$base.search-tpl]]</div>
    <button class="search_button">Search</button>
```

```
#header label{
    display:none;
}

#header input{
    width:88%;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0 0 0 10%;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:0px;
}

#header button{
    width:12%;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-image:url('../images/transparent_search_icon30x30.png');
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

.search_button:active > .search_function{
    display:all;
}
.search_function{
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: Are you interested in jQuery solution?

Comment: If you can explain how i implement that in my situation, sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first include jQuery library in the `<head>` section of your document e.g.

Google CDN version

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or download the compressed, production [jQuery 1.11.0](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js) and put it in your root folder then include it like this

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

then add below script just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $('.search_button').click(function() {
      if($('.search_function').css('display') === 'none') {
         $('.search_function').slideToggle(350);
      }
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Af6v8/)**</kbd>